# r-exams generates invalid QTI for cloze exercise

Tags: r-exams

I am running into a weird situation with r-exams where it "randomly" generates valid and an invalid QTI 2.1 files for the same exercise. I have created a MRE with two *almost* identical Rmd files [here](https://gist.github.com/mhils/22c735725883e901537280255c339242). In a nutshell, the only difference between the two exercises are the actual solution strings in `exsolution`.

If I look at the generated XML files, one of them contains `-Inf` as the minimum score at various places, whereas the other has `0` (which I think is the correct behavior).

repro_140893190_section_1_item_1_cloze.xml

```
[...]
<outcomeDeclaration identifier="MINSCORE" cardinality="single" baseType="float">
<defaultValue>
<value baseType="float">0</value>
</defaultValue>
</outcomeDeclaration>
[...]
```

repro_140893190_section_2_item_1_cloze.xml

```
[...]
<outcomeDeclaration identifier="MINSCORE" cardinality="single" baseType="float">
<defaultValue>
<value baseType="float">-Inf</value>
</defaultValue>
</outcomeDeclaration>
[...]
```

For reference, the full XML files are [here](https://gist.github.com/mhils/6210df113b0aa9e2a305015823484631). `-Inf` seems to be invalid and will cause OLAT's QTI interpreter to skip the exercise. I have no real good explanation for the difference. r-exams does not print any errors and r-exams's stress test works fine. Changing the order of exercises does not change the outcome, nor does including only one of them. I am using r-exams 2.4-0 from r-forge with R 4.0.3 on Windows 10. Is this a bug in r-exams, or somewhere else?

Comment: OK, this is caused by using "string" types for numeric answers which is subsequently misinterpreted by `exams_eval`. Using "num" instead avoids the problem. Also using the default `eval` would avoid the problem. But I guess you went this way because you were trying to get the following evaluation rule: 1/14 point for every correct entry in the table, and -1/14 point for every incorrect entry. Is that what you want? Not sure if this is supported at the moment, will have to check...

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply! "string" was intentional because some of the numbers can be "?". I guess I expected exams_eval to treat solution strings as opaque blobs. :) And yes, evaluation rule is intentional (more total points, but that doesn't change the general idea).

Comment: Brief update: I have fixed the `Inf` issue now in the development version of `exams` on R-Forge (https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=1337). But I haven't figured out yet whether your intended evaluation strategy is possible. It should be...will post a full answer when I have sorted that out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues with the evaluation strategy here and both are finally fixed now in version 2.4-0.

1. The string item with solution 10 was misinterpreted as a schoice item with two options (true + false). And this lead to the Inf issue, which was already fixed previously (see comments above).
2. Setting the negative points for string items within a cloze did not work correctly yet, but finally does. To get the desired evaluation strategy you need to specify:

   ```
   exams2openolat(..., eval = exams_eval(negative = TRUE), cloze = list(minvalue = 0))
   ```

   First, this generally enables negative points which, by default, means that an incorrect string (or num or schoice) answer yield a substraction of the same amount of points that the correct answer would have added. Second, for cloze questions the minimum number of points is set to zero, i.e., when summing up the points for all sub-items the worst case is no points.